# SQL ORACLE - SELECT dentro de um trigger

Tags: sql

Quando tento executar um trigger que recorre a esta função dá-me erro dizendo que a tabela está em mutação.

Função:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_tipo_inst (pCodI t_instituicao.id%TYPE) RETURN INTEGER IS
   resultado t_instituicao.deEnsino%TYPE;
   resultadoSec INTEGER;
BEGIN

    SELECT deEnsino
    INTO resultado
    FROM t_instituicao
    WHERE id=pCodI;

    SELECT count(*)
    INTO resultadoSec
    FROM t_pessoa
    WHERE idinst=pCodI;

    IF UPPER(resultado)='S' THEN
        IF resultadoSec=0 THEN
            RETURN -2;
        ELSE
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;


EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         RETURN -1;
END;
/
```

Mas se apenas executar a função desta maneira já não me dá nenhum tipo de erro:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_tipo_inst (pCodI t_instituicao.id%TYPE) RETURN INTEGER IS
   resultado t_instituicao.deEnsino%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT deEnsino
    INTO resultado
    FROM t_instituicao
    WHERE id=pCodI;

    IF UPPER(resultado)='S' THEN
        RETURN 1;
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;


EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         RETURN -1;
END;
/
```

**Nota:** Os `SELECT` sozinhas funcionam bem e a base de dados tem todas as tabelas necessárias.

O erro está mesmo na construção desta função, mas não percebo onde me enganei.

Comment: Se a trigger for em uma das duas tabelas da function dá este erro pois se está usando uma tabela em mutação. O que se precisa fazer ?

Comment: @Gabriel, ainda está com o problema?

Comment: Não , já consegui soluciona-lo. Obrigado